# How can I use select() to monitor an object?

Tags: c++, linux, networking

From [here](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select%22), it says that `select()` is used to "monitor multiple file descriptors, waiting until one or more of the file descriptors become "ready" for some class of I/O operation (e.g., input possible)". Then I looked at the [Beej's guide for socket programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/advanced.html#select), they used `select()` to monitor socket file descriptor.

In short, the tutorials and man pages said that `select()` operates on **file descriptor**. However, I came across a piece of code that uses`select()` to monitor an **object**. Code:

```
class SomeObject
{
    public:
        static SomeObject *_pInstance;
        //...some other methods...
}
```

---

```
SomeObject *SomeObject::_pInstance = new SomeObject();    
SomeObject &refObj = *SomeObject::_pInstance;
fd_set fdAllSet, fdReadableSet;
int nReadyHandles = 0;

FD_SET( refObj, &fdAllsSet ); //<---this line

while (1)
{
    fdReadableSet = fdAllSet;

    nReadyHandles = select( maxFd+1, &fdReadableSet, NULL, NULL, &someWaitTime );

    while (nReadyHandles > 0)
    {
        if (FD_ISSET(refObj, &fdReadableSet))
        {//do something
            FD_CLR(refObj, &fdReadableSet);
        }
    }
}
```

So the question is, how does `select()` determine if my "object is ready"? And why is [`FD_SET()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fd_set) not giving any compile error since the first argument suppose to be an `int` instead of `refObj`?

Comment: Maybe, FD_SET macro is redefined to use the FD member of the SomeObject !? Where did you get this code ?

Comment: You need to show us the *full* declaration of `class SomeObject` to see why this works.  For it to work it must wrap a file descriptor; it would be interesting to see how that works...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FD_SET and friends take an integer as the first argument...

```
void FD_CLR(int fd, fd_set *set);
int  FD_ISSET(int fd, fd_set *set);
void FD_SET(int fd, fd_set *set);
```

So the only way your code can compile is if either (a) SomeObject has a user-defined `SomeObject::operator int()` conversion operator that returns the file descriptor:

```
class SomeObject
{
    int my_fd;

    operator int() { return my_fd; }
};
```

or (b) the FD_* operations are defined as real functions (and not macros) and there are user-defined overloads of FD_* that take SomeObject and extract/map them to an fd and then call the original system version:

```
void FD_CLR(const SomeObject& so, fd_set *set)
{
    FD_CLR(so.my_fd, set);
}

int  FD_ISSET(const SomeObject& so, fd_set *set)
{
    return FD_ISSET(so.my_fd, set);
}

void FD_SET(const SomeObject& so, fd_set *set)
{
    return FD_SET(so.my_fd, set);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! `SomeObject::operator int()` is overloaded indeed! `operator int()` actually returns a file descriptor of an opened driver.

Comment: The `FD_SET` etc. may not be proper functions, but macros defined using the preprocessor. In that case they can not be overloaded.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: true, and on Linux at least they are defined as macros.  Clarification added.

Answer (score 2):

At a guess, the class `SomeObject` has an overload for cast to integer, that returns a file descriptor for, whatever it does.

Answer (score -1):

select() and FD_SET work on file descriptors, which are actually integers, not pointers to "SomeObject".